# Retrieving the PropertyDescriptor of a nested object

Tags: c#, nested-class, propertydescriptor

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        object o;
        Person p = new Person { FirstName = "John", Surname = "Henry" };
        Citizen c = new Citizen { Country = "Canada", ResidentName = p };
        SportsFan sf = new SportsFan { Sport = "Hockey", Fan = c };

        Discoverer<SportsFan>.SimpleExample("Sport", "Hockey",out o);
        Discoverer<SportsFan>.NestedProperyExample("Fan.Citizen.FirstName", "John",out o);
    }

    private class Person
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Surname
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    private class Citizen
    {
        public Person ResidentName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string Country
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    private class SportsFan
    {
        public string Sport
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Citizen Fan
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    private class Discoverer<T>
    {
        public static void SimpleExample(string propName, string objResultToString,out Object obj)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor propDesc;
            propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))[propName];               

            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propDesc.PropertyType);
            obj = converter.ConvertFromString(objResultToString);                   
        }

        public static void NestedProperyExample(string propName, string objResultToString, out Object obj)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor propDesc = null;
            obj = null;
            string[] nestedProperties = propName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties("Form1." + nestedProperties[0])[nestedProperties[1]];
            for (int i = 1; i < nestedProperties.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (propDesc != null)
                    propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(propDesc.GetType())[nestedProperties[i + 1]];
            }

            if (propDesc != null)
            {
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propDesc.PropertyType);
                obj = converter.ConvertFromString(objResultToString);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

The code works for the `simpleExample`.  On the `NestedPropertyExample`, the first assignment to `PropDesc` returns `null`.  When I check `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties("Form1." + nestedProperties[0])`, it returns a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` of one item and that is Length.

Why am I not returning more `PropertyDesriptor` items?  Am I going about this the correct way?

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 2):

The `NestedProperyExample` method is misspelled a bit, but don't mind -- it's not the problem (: Actually, the problem might be, that `NestedProperyExample` method calls the `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Object)` overload, passing it some string `("Form1." + nestedProperties[0])`. As per docs ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybh0y4fd.aspx)), it acts very much like just `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(string))`. `string`'s got only one simple property, its `Length`, -- and that's why `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` does not return any more `PropertyDescriptor` items.

This answers your direct question, but your intentions are unclear to me. May be if you could rephrase your question and state clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code, you'll likely get a better answer.